# iOS fade audio on app low memory warning

Tags: ios, ios5, audio, volume

I'm looking for a way to utilize the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to fade out the music playing in my app before killing the audio player. I want to fade the music and remove the player from memory without affecting the system's volume (or at least by resetting the systems volume when I'm done.) I only need to support iOS 5+.

The reason I ask the question here is:

1. I do not have access to the code actually playing the music, it's in a 3rd party framework (so I think my only solution is to fall back on adjusting the system volume.)
2. All the solutions I've found so far are quite old, hackish, and/or come with caveats about not being accepted by the App store, etc. etc.

Is there an acceptable way to fade the iPhone's audios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the realm of allowed APIs, only the user can control the system volume.  There is no way for your app to adjust it.  As you mention, accessing these other APIs will not be allowed in the app store, and may require a jailbroken device.

Which 3rd party framework are you using?  Can you check to see if it is using a standard audio player inside of it, such as `AVAudioPlayer`?  If so, you may be able to modify it that way.

**Update:** as Randy points out below, you can actually do this by controlling the iPod's volume:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.05];
```

Comment: This does change the *system volume* on my iPad (iOS 5) and iPhone (iOS 6): `[MPMusicPlayerController setVolume: 0.4];`

Comment: I'm using the [rdio ios sdk](http://developer.rdio.com/docs/read/iOS) which does not require the `AVFoundation.framework` that would be needed for the `AVAudioPlayer`, but it does requires the `AudioToolbox.framework`, which I believe is needed for Core Audio.

Comment: @RandyMarsh According to the documentation, that will only set the "audio playback volume for the music player".

Comment: @RandyMarsh surprisingly that actually affects the volume displayed in the MPVolumeView slider and the output of my app. This is what I just tried: `[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.05];` Now I just need to build code to fade it :)

Comment: @Aaron But if you change the "iPod" music player's volume, you actually change the system volume.

Answer (score 1):

If you do end up finding a way to at least access the player, here's a couple of ways this can be done.

Running in a `while-loop`

```
-(void)fadeOut
{
    while (data.volume > 0) {
        data.volume = data.volume - 0.1;
    }
    [data stop];
    data = nil;
}
```

Or, using a timer:

```
- (void)fadeOutWithTimer
{
    if (data.volume > 0.1) {
        data.volume = data.volume - 0.1;
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeOutWithTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
    } else {
        [data stop];
        data = nil;
    }
}
```